# How to Limit or restrict user to upload only image files at server side not on client side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to restrict user to upload only images type file that I want from server side . i have some thing missing in my code can any help me . Thanks in advance
I done client side restriction by 
 
This is able to restrict user to some extent but if user select all file during browse button click then it can upload any thing.

```
 <?php

//image script
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

$fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$image = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$image = addslashes($image);
fclose($fp);


if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$fileName = addslashes($fileName);
}








$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db_dat";

$conn=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$query = "INSERT INTO upload (name, size, type, image,passport_no,dateofissue,dateofexpiry,placeofissue ) ".
"VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$image','".$passno."','".$doi."','".$doe."','".$poi."')";

mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('Error, query failed'); 


echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the `accept` HTML attribute?

```html
<form action="form-handler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div>
  <input id="myfile" name="myfile" type="file" accept="image/*">
 </div>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/belross/aL30bqjd/

Comment: I want from server side not from client side

Answer (score 0):

```
            if ((($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'image/gif') || ($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'image/jpeg') || ($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'image/png'))
    {
    image file code
    }
    else
    {
    error message code
   }
```

Try this code for image validation in php.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with uploaded file type

like

```
$type = explode('/', $_FILES['file']['type']);

if($type[0] == "image") {
  //do something here
}
```